# Is there an eclipse equivalent to emacs M-/ (dabbrev-expand)?

Tags: eclipse, emacs

To quote emacs help, M-/ is:

> (dabbrev-expand ARG)
>
> Expand previous word "dynamically".
>
> Expands to the most recent, preceding
>   word for which this is a prefix. If no
>   suitable preceding word is found,
>   words following point are considered. 
>   If still no suitable word is found,
>   then look in the buffers accepted by
>   the function pointed out by variable
>   `dabbrev-friend-buffer-function'.

In other words, if somewhere in program there is a variable called `reallyLongVariableName` and I type `rea`M-/ then emacs automatically fills in the rest. If more than one match exists (ex, `reallyUglyVariableName`) then M-/ cycles thru them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it exists since [eclipse3.1](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1-200506271435/eclipse-news-all.html) and was tracked by [bug 11668](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11668)
("Add emacs-style "Alt-/" hippie auto completion").

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

> Text editors now support word completion.
>   In text editors you can complete a prefix to a word occurring in any of the currently open editors or buffers.
>   The default key binding for word completion is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on the Mac).

---

Note: if you repeat the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> key combination, it will cycle amongst all the word beginning with the current prefix, starting with the closest one from the current edit position.

Comment: thanks! I'm on a mac so, no wonder the alt-/ didn't work for me. Hippie indeed.